How do you use polymorphism with Go maps?
I'm curious on what kind of patterns should used in Go for such cases. So let's suppose, you have a Request struct that holds some information for making an HTTP request, along with the parameters that can be sent in the payload and their respective validations. Now different type of validations would be applicable on the basis of the data type of the parameter, so I decided to use a map[string]Validations, where I could store the type of Validations mentioned in the Validations union (basically, being able to accomodate both IntValidations & StrValidations in the same map).
But the below code would result in an error because Validations can only be used as a type parameter, so how can we achieve this in Go? In Java this could be easily achieved with polymorphism, where Validation would be the parent class and int and float validations would be the child classes, so later on we could easily instantiate a HashMap of Validations.
Note: I would want to avoid the usage of map[string]interface{}.
type Validations interface {
IntValidations | StrValidations
}

type IntValidations struct {
  MaxVal int
  MinVal int
}

type StrValidations struct {
  MinLength int
  MaxLength int
  Regex string 
}

type Request struct {
 Path string 
 Payload map[string]Validations // Error: Validations cannot be used outside of a type constraint.
}


Usemap[string]Validation where Validation is an interface with methods appropriate for a validation.  Example type Validation interface { Do(<insert args here>) error }

I see, but how will I be able to utilise this and populate IntValidations and StrValidations structs with this.. Could you please elaborate a bit more on this? Are you suggesting to get rid of the two structs and instead perform validations in the Do method?

Implement Do methods on the IntValidation and StrValidations types.  See the Tour of Go for information on how to implement a method and how methods relate to interfaces.

As pointed out by @Cerise Limón in the comments, you can do it like so
package main

type Validators interface {
    Validate(value any) error // Can return bool also
}

type IntValidator struct {
    MaxVal int
    MinVal int
}

func (intValidator *IntValidator) Validate(value any) error {
    // run validations
    return nil
}

type StrValidator struct {
    MinLength int
    MaxLength int
    Regex     string
}

func (strValidator *StrValidator) Validate(value any) error {
    // run validations
    return nil
}

type Request struct {
    Path    string
    Payload map[string]Validations
}

Now you can add validators with
func main() {
    request := Request{Payload: make(map[string]Validations)}
    request.Payload["myIntVar"] = &IntValidations{MinVal: 10, MaxVal: 20}
    request.Payload["myStrVar"] = &IntValidations{MinLen: 10, MaxLen: 15, Regex: "[a-z]+"}

    if err := request.Payload["myIntVar"].Validate(13); err != nil {
        panic("could not validate")
    }
}


Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. But just one more follow up question. What if I there was a case where one would want to create a similar map accomodating multiple similar types, but contrary to this specific use case, the use of a method such as Validate is not required at all. How would we achieve the same then?

@ansme Describe what makes the types "similar".

@CeriseLimón Let's just say, it's a map of map[string]Animal, where we could hold similar types as values such as type Cat struct, type Dog struct, where these structs just hold basic fields like name string, neutered bool etc..  but let us assume that they don't require any functionality... therefore, the underlying interface Animal does not have any methods defined to it. Then how will we be able to create a map[string]Animal?

@ansme Follow the pattern in this answer, but use an empty Validate method.

@asme, you can make a simple Validate method that has 0 args, returns nothing and implement it with empty body to specify that it implemeta the Validator interface but does nothing.

@TimsibAdnap Instead of using any Is there a way to implement the validate method with int, string arguments specific to the respective implementing structs?

Yes, you can using generic interface. But generic interfaces cannot be stored in a map. Check this. I would recommend you keep it as any and inside the Validate function check it like if intVal, ok := value.(int); !ok { return err }
